# rosmake rgbdslam_freiburg

Tags: ros, rgbdslam-freiburg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have problem with compiling rgbdslam_freiburg in ROS Fuerte,

I have installed rgbdslam_freiburg and g2o in fuerte_workspace using

```
svn co http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbdslam_freiburg 
svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/vslam/trunk/g2o
```

also installed ros-fuerte-vision-opencv , ros-fuerte-octomap , ros-fuerte-octomap-mapping and modified CMakeLists.txt of rgbdslam to adapt with g2o package dependent and remarked SiftGPU

compiled first g2o without failure, but got error compiling rgbdslam as following

```
  /home/reza/fuerte_workspace/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:273: undefined reference to `g2o::get_monotonic_time()'
  CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/transformation_estimation.o: In function `g2o::G2OBatchStatistics::globalStats()':
  /home/reza/fuerte_workspace/g2o/include/g2o/core/batch_stats.h:73: undefined reference to `g2o::G2OBatchStatistics::_globalStats'
  CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/transformation_estimation.o: In function `g2o::LinearSolverCholmod<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >::computeSymbolicDecomposition(g2o::SparseBlockMatrix<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > const&)':
  /home/reza/fuerte_workspace/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:332: undefined reference to `g2o::get_monotonic_time()'
  CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/transformation_estimation.o: In function `g2o::LinearSolverCholmod<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >::solvePattern(g2o::SparseBlockMatrix<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >&, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > const&, g2o::SparseBlockMatrix<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > const&)':
  /home/reza/fuerte_workspace/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:235: undefined reference to `g2o::MarginalCovarianceCholesky::MarginalCovarianceCholesky()'
  /home/reza/fuerte_workspace/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:236: undefined reference to `g2o::MarginalCovarianceCholesky::setCholeskyFactor(int, int*, int*, double*, int*)'
  /home/reza/fuerte_workspace/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:238: undefined reference to `g2o::MarginalCovarianceCholesky::computeCovariance(g2o::SparseBlockMatrix<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > const&)'
  CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/transformation_estimation.o: In function `g2o::G2OBatchStatistics::globalStats()':
  /home/reza/fuerte_workspace/g2o/include/g2o/core/batch_stats.h:73: undefined reference to `g2o::G2OBatchStatistics::_globalStats'
  CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/transformation_estimation.o: In function `g2o::LinearSolverCholmod<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >::solvePattern(g2o::SparseBlockMatrix<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >&, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > const&, g2o::SparseBlockMatrix<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > const&)':
  /home/reza/fuerte_workspace/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:245: undefined reference to `g2o::MarginalCovarianceCholesky::~MarginalCovarianceCholesky()'
  /home/reza/fuerte_workspace/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:245: undefined reference to `g2o::MarginalCovarianceCholesky::~MarginalCovarianceCholesky()'
  CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/transformation_estimation.o: In function `g2o::LinearSolverCholmod<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >::solveBlocks(double**&, g2o::SparseBlockMatrix<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > const&)':
  /home/reza/fuerte_workspace/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:194: undefined reference to `g2o::MarginalCovarianceCholesky::MarginalCovarianceCholesky()'
  /home/reza/fuerte_workspace/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:195: undefined reference to `g2o::MarginalCovarianceCholesky::setCholeskyFactor(int, int*, int*, double*, int*)'
  /home/reza/fuerte_workspace/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:197: undefined reference to `g2o::MarginalCovarianceCholesky::computeCovariance(double**, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
  CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/transformation_estimation.o: In function `g2o::G2OBatchStatistics::globalStats()':
  /home/reza/fuerte_workspace/g2o/include/g2o/core/batch_stats.h:73: undefined reference to `g2o::G2OBatchStatistics::_globalStats'
  CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/transformation_estimation.o: In function `g2o::LinearSolverCholmod<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >::solveBlocks(double**&, g2o::SparseBlockMatrix<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > const&)':
  /home/reza/fuerte_workspace/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:204: undefined reference to `g2o::MarginalCovarianceCholesky::~MarginalCovarianceCholesky()'
  /home/reza/fuerte_workspace/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:204: undefined reference to `g2o::MarginalCovarianceCholesky::~MarginalCovarianceCholesky()'
  CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/transformation_estimation.o: In function `g2o::LinearSolverCholmod<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >::solve(g2o::SparseBlockMatrix<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > const&, double*, double*)':
  /home/reza/fuerte_workspace/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:124: undefined reference to `g2o::get_monotonic_time()'
  CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/transformation_estimation.o: In function `g2o::G2OBatchStatistics::globalStats()':
  /home/reza/fuerte_workspace/g2o/include/g2o/core/batch_stats.h:73: undefined reference to `g2o::G2OBatchStatistics::_globalStats'
  CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/transformation_estimation.o: In function `g2o::LinearSolverCholmod<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >::solve(g2o::SparseBlockMatrix<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > const&, double*, double*)':
  /home/reza/fuerte_workspace/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:149: undefined reference to `g2o::get_monotonic_time()'
  CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/graph_manager2.o: In function `~RobustKernel':
  /home/reza/fuerte_workspace/g2o/include/g2o/core/robust_kernel.h:57: undefined reference to `vtable for g2o::RobustKernel'
  /home/reza/fuerte_workspace/g2o/include/g2o/core/robust_kernel.h:57: undefined reference to `vtable for g2o::RobustKernel'
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[3]: *** [../bin/rgbdslam] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/reza/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/reza/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/reza/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package rgbdslam written to:ve 48/49 Complete ]
[ rosmake ]    /home/reza/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130928-160820/rgbdslam/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rgbdslam [FAIL] [ 644.51 seconds ]                     
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package rgbdslam.  Active 48/49 Complete ]
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Cleaned 49 packages.                                                
[ rosmake ] Built 49 packages with 1 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/reza/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130928-160820
```

any help? , please
Reza,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84541/rosmake-rgbdslam_freiburg/) by [Reza](https://answers.ros.org/users/126/reza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2013-09-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-10-21**:
Rgbdslam depends on the fuerte package of g2o not the latest version from git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sorry, it was my fault, I should not remove  from rgbdslam manifest.xml, it is now compiled.

---

Originally posted by [Reza](https://answers.ros.org/users/126/reza/) with karma: 116 on 2013-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0